# 'babelHelpers.taggedTemplateLiteral' is undefined in react native when using tagged template strings

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, template-strings

I'm trying to use tagged template strings in react native app (rn version 0.16) like this

```
let i18n = function(){
       return 'should be fun';
   };
console.log(i18n`not fun`);
```

I get exception -  'babelHelpers.taggedTemplateLiteral' is undefined;

if I use just template string like:

```
console.log(`Fun`);
```

It is working.

Since 0.16 rn moved to babel 6 and may be it is not only rn specific. 
I have check packager and "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals" included.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  How?  Thanks

Comment: @Udi Not yet, if I will find the answer I will update this post

Comment: @Udi I solve it by updating to RN 18. There are some other issue there but this one is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by updating to RN 18.